# sectionForSectionIndexTitle retrieve previous section

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView with sectionIndexTitles. Here's my data source :

```
let sSectionTitles = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","#"]
var sectionTitles = [String]()

func sectionIndexTitlesForTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
        return sSectionTitles
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, atIndex index: Int) -> Int {
        var section = 0
        if let selectedSection = sectionTitles.indexOf(title) {
            section = selectedSection
        } else {
            section = index
        }
        return section
}
```

The variable `sectionTitles` is a similar array to `sSectionTitles` except that it only contains section indexes that are valid. For example, if I have no Contact with their name starting with the letter D, then "D" won't be in `sectionTitles`.

I'm trying to replicate the behavior in the Contact application :

- If the user clicks on the Index title "D" and if there is at least one contact in the B section, then scroll to this section.
- Else, scroll to the previous section available. (In this example, if there are no contacts for the B and C letter then scroll to A)

I've been stuck of this for many hours I still don't know how I could apply this logic. I thought about using a recursive function but I didn't manage to pull this off. Does someone has any lead on how this could be achieved?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it by recursion. Use another helper function to retrieve the appropriate index and call it from tableview data source function. Example,

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, atIndex index: Int) -> Int {
    var section = getSectionIndex(title) 
    return section
}        

//recursive function to get section index
func getSectionIndex(title: String) -> Int {
    let tmpIndex = sectionTitles.indexOf(title)
    let mainIndex = sSectionTitles.indexOf(title)
    if mainIndex == 0 {
        return 0
    }
    if tmpIndex == nil {
        let newTitle = sSectionTitles[mainIndex!-1]
        return getSectionIndex(newTitle)
    }
    return tmpIndex!
}
```

Comment: I was trying to achieve something similar, but I was using the index rather than the title and that's probably why this confused me so much. I gotta say that recursion is not my cup of tea but this cleaned up most of my confusion of the subject. Thanks a lot.